# ftp transfer using codeigniter version 2

Tags: codeigniter, upload, ftp

```
$this->load->library('ftp');
$config['hostname'] = 'text.com';
$config['username'] = 'test';
$config['password'] = '12345678';
$config['port']     = 21;
$config['passive']  = FALSE;
$config['debug']    = TRUE; 
$conn           = $this->ftp->connect($config);

if($conn){
       $this->ftp->upload('/ftp1_uploads/images/test.zip','/ftp2_uploads/images/test.zip');
}
```

I want to transfer from ftp1 to ftp2 not the same domain.

Return error below using codeigniter version 2

```
An Error Was Encountered
Unable to locate the source file. Please check your path.
```

I already try rename the file using the same path its works. but when I transfer from ftp1 to ftp2 different domain it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't transfer files from ftp1 to ftp2 without using interim location, your algorithm is: download from ftp1 to local, upload from local to ftp2